# Bash script while loop won't work: "-le unary operator expected"

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run a bash script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

set i=1991

while [ $i -le 2017 ]
do
    echo "looping and doing stuff"
    $i++
done
echo all done
```

I get the following error:

```
[: -le: unary operator expected
```

I have also tried changing the code like so:

```
 #!/bin/bash

set i=1991


while (( $i <= 2017 ));
do
    echo "looping";
    (( $i++ ));
done

echo ALL done
```

which gives me this error:

```
((: <= 2017 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<= 2017 ")
```

and I've tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set i=1991

while [ "$i" -le "2017" ]
do
    echo "looping"
    $i++
done

echo ALL done
```

And I get this:

```
[: : integer expression expected
```

I think it's a stupid syntax error but unfortunately I can't seem to figure it out. My version of bash is 4.3.48.

Thank you!

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) points out many such common syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` is used to set the positional parameters, not ordinary variables.

```
$ unset i
$ set i=1991
$ echo "$1"
i=1991
$ echo "$i"

$
```

The `i=1991` is a single argument to `set`, treated as a literal string, not an assignment of any kind.

Just drop the `set`:

```
i=1991
while (( i < 2017 )); 
  ...
  ((i++))
done
```

Comment: You might also have a `echo "$i"` in there, just to show that it's empty (if an `unset i` is added as a first line).